# Efficient Multi-Voltage Output in PoE Circuit via Custom Transformer

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, poe

I'm working to maximize the efficiency of the isolation circuit on a PoE device in order to maximize power delivery to the device itself. Since the PoE spec requires isolation, I was wondering if it would be theoretically possible to have more efficient generation of secondary voltages via the isolation transformer with multiple different windings. This reference circuit from Maxim Integrated makes it look like it's possible:

https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/reference-design-center/ref-circuits/6989.html

But is this an efficient/recommended way to achieve multiple secondary voltages versus separate 3.3 V, 5 V, 12 V linear voltage converter ICs?

Comment: Depends on your cross regulation requirements. Have you contemplated just generating the highest voltage and buck down from there?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the option I'm comparing: generate multiple secondaries from the transformer vs single 48v output from the transformer and multiple down converters afterward.

Answer (score 0):

If your doing DIY POE (not according to spec and the device won't be plugged into other POE devices that aren't yours, there are some cheaper devices sourced from china that don't follow the spec).

If you are following the spec (and you do want POE compatibility, like connecting to POE switch, then the device will need to negotiate for more power with the host and the host will need to be compatible with the level of power that the device needs), then just use a controller that is compatible with the power level you need.

[image]
Source: https://www.black-box.de/en-de/page/23894/Resources/Technical-Resources/Black-Box-Explains/lan/PoE-in-Networking

After the POE controller you can use a DC\DC converter to break out the voltages you need for your power rails.

Comment: I understand everything before the DC/DC converter: I'll be using something like the TPS2372 or MAX5996C then passing that power to the DC converter which must be isolated from the PD circuit to comply with the PoE spec.